# How can I remove non-breaking spaces from a text file in bash?

Tags: bash, space

I have a csv file with text and numbers.

If a number is bigger than 1000, formatted like this: 1 000,
so it has a space as thousand separator, but it is not space. I tried to `sed` it, and it worked where real space was, but not in this format.

It is also not TAB, I removed all the TABs with "expand -t 1".

The following is a line that demonstrates the issue:

```
x17_Provident_GDN_REMARKETING_provident.hu_listák;Display_Hálózat;Szeged;2021-03-09;Kedd;Mobil;HUF;1 736;9;130.83;0.00
```

In penultimate row, in column 8:  `1 736` 
is the problem.

And running this: `grep -E -m 1 -e '[;]1[^;]+736[;]' <yourfile.csv | hexdump -C`

gives:

```
00000000  78 31 37 5f 50 72 6f 76  69 64 65 6e 74 5f 47 44  |x17_Provident_GD|
00000010  4e 5f 52 45 4d 41 52 4b  45 54 49 4e 47 5f 70 72  |N_REMARKETING_pr|
00000020  6f 76 69 64 65 6e 74 2e  68 75 5f 6c 69 73 74 c3  |ovident.hu_list.|
00000030  a1 6b 3b 44 69 73 70 6c  61 79 5f 48 c3 a1 6c c3  |.k;Display_H..l.|
00000040  b3 7a 61 74 3b 53 7a 65  67 65 64 3b 32 30 32 31  |.zat;Szeged;2021|
00000050  2d 30 33 2d 30 39 3b 4b  65 64 64 3b 4d 6f 62 69  |-03-09;Kedd;Mobi|
00000060  6c 3b 48 55 46 3b 31 c2  a0 37 33 36 3b 39 3b 31  |l;HUF;1..736;9;1|
00000070  33 30 2e 38 33 3b 30 2e  30 30 0a                 |30.83;0.00.|
0000007b
```

Comment: `head -n 1 file.csv | hexdump -C`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thx for the formatting tips, I am newcomer here:)

Comment: The sequence that's being a problem for you is `c2 0a`. On its own, `0x0a` is a newline. To know what it means with `0xc2` before it requires knowing the encoding your file is in.

Comment: `c2 0a` is a [NO-BREAK SPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it was generated in Google Ads, downloaded as tsv file, actually in 3 tsv files, and than we used ```cat >> new_file.csv``` to have one big csv file. And it was done on MAC OS.

Comment: By the way, notice how I changed the formatting -- the trio of backticks need to be _on a line with nothing else_ to correctly start and end multi-line code formatting. When you have text right after the start of the block, that text is parsed as the name of the language to syntax-highlight the block in ("none" says not to syntax-highlight it at all), so it isn't read as content to be rendered. Whereas when you have less than one line, only a single backtick is enough; there's no need to triple them up.

Comment: @Cyrus Thx, so now I just try to figure out how to remove it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thx again for the formatting tips:)

Comment: @Cyrus It did not work. I tried:
```sed -z -i 's/\xc2\x0a//g' test4.csv
```
And with ```cat test4.csv
```
Had in the problematic row:
```x17_Provident_GDN_REMARKETING_provident.hu_listák;Display_Hálózat;Szeged;2021-03-09;Kedd;Mobil;HUF;1 736;9;130.83;0.00
```

Comment: What do you want to do after ? echo 'Your exemple line'  | awk -F';' '{gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$8);print $8}' 1736 !

Comment: @ctac_ thx it gives: 1736 :). THX! I would like to push the data, the csv file into postgresql database. Is there a solution where the rest of the data is untouched?

Comment: If the problem is only on field 8 : awk -F';' '{gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$8)}1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we know it is No break space, I simply sed it on mac with entry method:

```
opt+space
```

```
cat test4.csv | sed 's/ //g'
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to perl, you can use GNU `sed` with `LC_ALL=C`:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/\xc2\xa0//g'
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Under what circumstances is the `LC_ALL=C` required? I am probably naïve to say this, but bytes are bytes as far as sed is concerned, right?

Comment: `but bytes are bytes as far as sed is concerned` GNU sed has support for unicode. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Locale-Considerations

Answer (score 2):

It's a 2 byte, UTF-8 encoded [non breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) - `c2 a0`.

You can use `perl` to safely remove it.

```
perl -pe 's/\xc2\xa0//g' dirty.csv > clean.csv
```